Is the solution to this MIT 6.042 Discrete Math problem correct?
I'll help rewrite the mathematical expressions in LaTeX. Here's the text with LaTeX formatting:
Question: Is the solution to this MIT 6.042 Discrete Math problem correct?
This question is from the MIT 6.042 Discrete Mathematics course (Problem set 11, Problem 6, Part c).
I came across the solution sheet for this problem on GitHub: MIT 6.042 problem set solutions
Here's the relevant portion of the problem:
Three very rare DNA markers were found in the DNA collected at a crime scene. Only one in every 1,000 people has marker AA, one in every 3,000 people has marker BB, and one in every 5,000 people has marker CC. Joe the plumber was arrested and accused of committing the crime because he had all those markers present in his DNA. The prosecutor argues that the chances of any person having all three DNA markers is
$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C) = \frac{1}{1,000} \cdot \frac{1}{3,000} \cdot \frac{1}{5,000} = \frac{1}{15,000,000,000}$
which is less than the probability of finding such a person in the world population.
The part c is the question then asks, "What can you say about the probability of a person having all three markers if there is no independence between the markers?"
The solution provided in the GitHub repository states that:
"The probability is at most:
$P(C) = \frac{1}{5,000}$."
However, this conclusion seems incorrect to me. If the markers are not independent, we can't really determine the probability based solely on the individual probabilities $P(A)$, $P(B)$, and $P(C)$. For example, if the markers are strongly correlated, the probability could be significantly higher than $P(C)$.
Am I misunderstanding something here, or is the solution indeed incorrect? Any clarification or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Think about the Venn's diagram. The measure of the intersection of sets cannot be greater than the minimum.

The answer is correct. Because everybody who has all three markers has, by definition, marker $C$. So
$$
  P(A\cap B \cap C) ≤ P(C).
$$
This would be the case if everybody with marker $C$ also had both other markers, so this bound is sharp. Since $\frac1{1000} + \frac1{3000} + \frac1{5000} < 1$, it could also be that noone had more than one of these markers, which would make $P(A\cap B\cap C) = 0$. We can thus find no lower bound.

Yeah, i just got confused with words of the question I guess. Thanks a lot : )

$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A|B\cap C)P(B\cap C)=P(A|B\cap C)P(B|C)P(C)$
Since all probabilities are less than or equal to one,
$$P(A|B\cap C)P(B|C)P(C)\le P(B|C)P(C)\le P(C)=\frac{1}{5000}$$
